# Keeping flutter's styling separate / independent of view code

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So this is how I am styling a simple flutter button today -

```
FlatButton(
          child: Text('Hello'),
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.blue,
          colorBrightness: Brightness.dark, 
          disabledColor: Colors.blueGrey,
          highlightColor: Colors.red,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0)
        )
```

It seems like the view code for flutter requires styling to be built in with every component ? How can I keep this completely separate ? Something like what CSS (almost) does it for the web ? Seems like the code will be a lot of cleaner and I could also reuse my styles.

I could subclass something like the Brightness class for custom brightness, but that seems like an overkill.

Also, found this package today which gets me closer to what I want - https://pub.dev/packages/division

Ideally, what are some good practices to keep styling separate from the view code in flutter ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you might know, but you can declare common styling in your main.dart,

> For Button theme,

```
 ThemeData(
...

 buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        colorScheme: colorSchemeDark,
        splashColor: AppColors.themeColor.shade900,
        height: 50,
        highlightColor: AppColors.themeColor.shade800,
        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
      ),
)
```

> For card theme,

```
ThemeData(
...

 cardTheme: CardTheme(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, left: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8),
        elevation: 6.0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
      ),
)
```

I have created a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/05580cdd07f78114d05c702d5993d510)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can create create a Reusable `FlattButon` with default styles, and you can override the styles any time you want:

Example:

```
class MyFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFlatButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.onPressed,
    this.color = Colors.blue, // set default Values
    this.colorBrightness = Brightness.dark, //
    this.disabledColor = Colors.blueGrey, //
    this.highlightColor = Colors.red, //
    this.padding =
        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0), //
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Color color;
  final Brightness colorBrightness;
  final MaterialColor disabledColor;
  final MaterialColor highlightColor;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        '$text',
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      color: color,
      colorBrightness: colorBrightness,
      disabledColor: disabledColor,
      highlightColor: highlightColor,
      padding: padding,
    );
  }
}
```

and you can use it like MyFlatButton instead of FlatButton in your App

```
  child: MyFlatButton(
    text: 'Hello',
    onPressed: () {},
    color: Colors.cyan,
  ),
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to "completely" separate the style you can create an extra Class which holds the styles

```
class MyFlatButton2 extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyFlatButton2({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.onPressed,
    this.styles = const ButtonStyles(),
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final ButtonStyles styles;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final btnStyles = ButtonStyles();
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('$text'),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      color: styles.color ?? btnStyles.color,
      colorBrightness: styles.colorBrightness ?? btnStyles.colorBrightness,
      disabledColor: styles.disabledColor ?? btnStyles.disabledColor, 
      highlightColor: styles.highlightColor ?? btnStyles.highlightColor, 
      padding: styles.padding ?? btnStyles.padding,
    ); 
  }
}

// Styles Class
class ButtonStyles {
  final Color color;
  final Brightness colorBrightness;
  final MaterialColor disabledColor;
  final MaterialColor highlightColor;
  final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;

  const ButtonStyles({
    this.color = Colors.blue, // set default Values
    this.colorBrightness = Brightness.dark, //
    this.disabledColor = Colors.blueGrey, //
    this.highlightColor = Colors.red, //
    this.padding =
        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0), //
  });
}
```

And then you can use it 
with default style

```
  child: MyFlatButton2(
    text: 'Hello',
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
```

or you can override the style

```
  child: MyFlatButton2(
    text: 'Hello',
    onPressed: () {},
    styles: ButtonStyles(
      colorBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      color: Colors.green,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
    ),
  ),
```

**Extra**, you can also have some named constructors with predefined Styles

```
  factory ButtonStyles.predefinedStyle1() => ButtonStyles(
        color: Colors.green, // set default Values
        colorBrightness: Brightness.light, //
        disabledColor: Colors.red, //
        highlightColor: Colors.red, //
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 15.0),
  );
```

and then

```
  child: MyFlatButton2(
    text: 'Hello',
    onPressed: () {},
    styles: ButtonStyles.predefinedStyle1(),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package https://pub.dev/packages/division

it allows you to create styles for widgets, store them for reuse and more.

```
final textStyle = TxtStyle()
  ..textColor(Colors.white)
  ..fontSize(30)
  ..bold()
  ..italic()
  ..textAlign.start();

Text(
'hi',
style:textStyle
)
```